# WindowsFormsApp: Rename The Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

My Windows Form used to be called WindowsFormsApp1. 
I renamed it and all the components to "Shadow" 
When I click Start, then I right click "Shadow" on the taskbar, 
It says "WindowsFormApp1". How Do I Make It Shadow?

Comment: right-click the winformapp1 on solution explorer then rename and say yes to the references.

Comment: in the properties of the window, there should be something like title or name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under project name right click **Properties > Application > Assembly Information > Title** , then set it to *Mango*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `this.Text = "Mango";` to your Form_Load function and your form's name will change. Keep in mind that code will always overwrite your settings chosen in the property window.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this 2 simple steps. First right click inside that form. then select properties. you will see property toolbar opened at right side of your screen. now scroll down and you will see Text filed. Changing the value of text filed will do your desire job.
happy developing mate.

[image]

[image]